# "Name=AJAXREQUEST", "Value=_viewRoot" to set elementvalue of ajax field?

Tags: ajax, loadrunner

Looking at some old scripts to learn a bit I observe this in a web_submit_data:
"Name=AJAXREQUEST", "Value=_viewRoot", 
and
"Name=thenameoftheelementIwantToSet", "Value=thevalueIwantToSet",
(and more name-value pairs)

Is this a wayt to actually set a value if the elements name is 'thenameoftheelementIwantToSet' and the value is 'thevalueIwantToSet' ? And the name 'AJAXREQUEST', is it a reserved word as in actually stating that this element manipulation is to be done on a AjaxElemnt or could it say whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processing of these name / value pairs are done on the server your application or web page is running on. It's totally up to the app as to what is valid or not. From LoadRunner's perspective you're just passing a pair of strings.